# Generate a CSV File

Tags: csv, powershell-4.0

I am creating a powershell script, and one of the features is multi-user creation from a CSV.

I want it so after the script runs it clears the CSV file, then generates another with the correct headers.

**Relevant Code**

*Script Beginning*

```
[string]$csvpath = "multiusers.csv"  
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "multiusers.csv"
```

*Script End*

```
Clear-Content $csvpath
Write-Output "User,First Name,Surname,Job Title,Department,Ticket Number,Managers First Name,Managers Surname" `n`n|FT -AutoSize >>multiusers.csv
```

In my mind, this should work, however all this does is create one large header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using one long string as one column, seperate it to multiple strings first then Remove the  `| FT -AutoSize[...]` Part, create a custom object row and use `Export-CSV`

Also, some of your columns contains spaces, you need to add quotes between them

Try this instead:

```
"" | Select User,"First Name",Surname,"Job Title",Department,"Ticket Number","Managers First Name","Managers Surname"  | Export-csv multiusers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Another way using your string with split, like this:

```
$Columns = "User,First Name,Surname,Job Title,Department,Ticket Number,Managers First Name,Managers Surname" -split ","
"" | Select $Columns | Export-csv c:\multiusers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Or using `Out-File` if you don't want empty commas line.

```
$Columns = "User,First Name,Surname,Job Title,Department,Ticket Number,Managers First Name,Managers Surname" -split ","
(($Columns | % {'"{0}"' -f $_} ) -join ',') + "`n`n" | Out-File C:\multiusers.csv
```

Comment: I'm not selecting any fields from within the script though.

The CSV File is already generated. Once my colleagues fill in the CSV, and run it through the script they have to manually delete the users from the CSV other than the column headers. When user creations can be 200+, this can be time consuming.

I need it to automatically clear the file (I currently have it working), and then regenerate the CSV file with the correct column headers.

Comment: The Second one, causes the following in the CSV.

#TYPE Selected.System.String
"User","First Name","Surname","Job Title","Department","Ticket Number","Managers First Name","Managers Surname"
,,,,,,,

Comment: just add the `-NoTypeInformation` to the `Export-CSV` part. added to answer

Comment: I've done this, it still leaves ",,,,,,," however i need that removed also

Comment: it's just an empty line, if you don't want it use `Out-File` see updated answer

Comment: That Out-File Works